# array sorting php

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I've an array like this

```
Array
(

[0] => Array

        (
            [result] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [type] => ABC
                            [id] => 123232
                            [name] => Apple

                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [type] => DEF
                            [id] => 2323232
                            [name] => Banana

                        )

                )


            [title] => Cool
            [rank] => 2
        )

  [1] => Array
        (
            [result] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [type] => ZX
                            [id] => 3223
                            [name] => Danny

                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [type] => QWER
                            [id] => 2323232
                            [name] => Cactus

                        )

                )


            [title] => Hot
            [rank] => 1
        )


[3]..
[4]..and son on
```

I would like to sort by rank, is there any quick sort method in PHP to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [**usort**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) function:

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
    return $a['rank'] - $b['rank'];
}

$arr = /* your array */

usort($arr, "cmp");
```

[**See it**](http://www.ideone.com/C13YR)

To sort on rank in descending order (*question asked in comments*), you just reverse the order in the compare function:

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
    return $b['rank'] - $a['rank'];
           ^^           ^^
}
```

Comment: @codaddick; i really doesn't undestand how it works in all sorting  methods `$a -$b`; would you please describe or give me a link to underatand

Comment: @diEcho The comparison function only needs to return `0` if both are equal, a value `< 0` if the first element is lower and a value `> 0` if the first element is higher than the second. Since the ranks are numeric `$a - $b` accomplishes this.

Comment: @diEcho If they are equal, `0` will be returned, if `$a` is smaller, a negative number will be returned, if `$a` is bigger, a positive number will be returned.

Comment: @diEcho: The comparison function must return an integer less than, equal to, or greater than zero if the first argument is considered to be respectively less than, equal to, or greater than the second. One can use an else to achieve it but a simpler way is to do `return $a - $b;`

Comment: Thanks all for the super fast reply! wondering how to sort by descending for this case?

Answer (score 4):

You could use [`usort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php).

The example below requires >= PHP 5.3. If you don't have this version, just pass a reference to the callback.

```
usort($array, function($a, $b) {
   return $a['rank'] - $b['rank'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to sort an array, see : http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php